# Determining closest lists near any selected point

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I'm plotting several lists of data (constant lines of density, temperature quality, etc. on a pressure-enthalpy diagram), none of which are fitted well by `Interpolation` or `Fit`. Since each table/line represents a constant density (in this case), I want to determine what density is at any selected point based off of the two nearest density lines (blue).

[image]

- Blue points are data points in `rho` lists.
- Orange points are all points from my function `TotalClose` which returns one point from each `rho` list.
- Green points are from my function `PointClose`.
- Largest black point is set with `Manipulate` controls.

The `Locator` is on a log scale so `pt` makes it linear for calculations:

```
Control[{{pt0,{2295,Log@145}},Locator}]

pt={First@pt0,Exp@Last@pt0};
```

In my attempt I found the point from each `rho` list closest to the point `pt` selected with the `Locator`:

```
TotalClose[list_]:=First@Nearest[list[[#]],pt]&/@Range@Length@list;

PointClose[list_]:=Nearest[TotalClose[list],pt,2];
```

Functions are evaluated at `{rho1000,rho700,rho50,rho2,rho02}`

The green points `PointClose` returned are not correct here. It needs to return points from the `rho700` and `rho50` lists. This would be easier if I could fit these lists to a function but they won't.

I was planning on using the lever rule to determine what the density would be at the selected point. I am stuck as to how to get which two `rho` lists are either immediately to the left and right or above and below `pt`.

I tried changing the `DistanceFunction` in `Nearest` with no luck:

```
 DistanceFunction->(((#1[[1]]-#2[[1]])^2+(Log@#1[[2]]-Log@#2[[2]])^2)^1/2&)
```

Here are the `rho` lists that make the blue constant density lines:

```
rho1000 = {{2674.112, 10000.}, {2442.182, 9000.}, {2211.362, 
    8000.}, {1980.958, 7000.}, {1750.036, 6000.}, {1517.27, 
    5000.}, {1280.666, 4000.}, {1036.931, 3000.}, {779.806, 
    2000.}, {493.584, 1000.}, {461.831, 900.}, {429.132, 
    800.}, {395.296, 700.}, {360.063, 600.}, {323.059, 
    500.}, {283.706, 400.}, {241.029, 300.}, {193.124, 200.}, {135.03,
     100.}, {120.986, 80.}, {105.405, 60.}, {87.389, 40.}, {64.549, 
    20.}, {48.572, 10.}, {44.443, 8.}, {39.658, 6.}, {34.028, 
    4.098}, {29.72, 2.984}, {25.44, 2.181}, {21.188, 1.692}, {16.964, 
    1.521}, {16.964, 0.05}};

rho700 = {{5000., 8801.33}, {4642.4, 8000.}, {4207.4, 7000.}, {3784.3,
     6000.}, {3371.92, 5000.}, {2968.32, 4000.}, {2570.4, 
    3000.}, {2173.14, 2000.}, {1767.73, 1000.}, {1726.18, 
    900.}, {1684.37, 800.}, {1642.24, 700.}, {1599.79, 
    600.}, {1556.95, 500.}, {1513.7, 400.}, {1469.97, 300.}, {1425.7, 
    200.}, {1380.8, 100.}, {1377.65, 93.070}};

rho50 = {{5000., 331.29}, {4673.64, 300.}, {3703.16, 200.}, {2815.85, 
    100.}, {2739.86, 91.84}, {2444, 71}, {2100, 50}, {1900, 
    37}, {1700, 26}, {1490, 15.5}, {1300, 9.5}, {1050, 4.1}, {820, 
    1.6}, {590, 0.5}, {425, 0.2}, {325, 0.1}, {250, 0.05}};

rho2 = {{5000., 13.07}, {4184.58, 10.}, {3693.09, 8.}, {3234.16, 
    6.}, {2802.61, 4.}, {2734.26, 3.68}, {2500, 3.3}, {2150, 
    2.5}, {1950, 2}, {1750, 1.5}, {1500, 1}, {1230, 0.6}, {1020, 
    0.38}, {815, 0.2}, {660, 0.115}, {450, 0.05}};

rho02 = {{5000., 1.31}, {4184.66, 1.}, {3692.28, 0.8}, {3232.73, 
    0.6}, {2803.20, 0.4}, {2626.43, 0.31}, {2500, 0.32}, {2250, 
    0.32}, {2000, 0.3}, {1840, 0.28}, {1660, 0.24}, {1480, 
    0.2}, {1250, 0.15}, {1000, 0.105}, {810, 0.08}, {550, 0.05}};
```

Comment: Why can't you use `Interpolation` of the data sets? You should be able to.

Comment: For instance, [this was generated by interpolating your points](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Ra0.png).

Comment: Wow I could never get the curves to look that nice! How exactly did you get that?

Some of the other data I'm plotting looks even worse with `Interpolation`, that and some don't pass the vertical line test

Comment: `f = Interpolation /@ Transpose @ rho1000`, for instance. This returns a list of two pure interpolating functions that you can plot parametrically: `ParametricPlot[Through@f@t, Evaluate@Flatten@{t, f[[1]]["Domain"]}, AspectRatio -> 1]`. I've been trying to figure out how to do the calculation of the nearest points on the curves, but haven't succeeded yet. Perhaps you can have a go with these interpolations.

Comment: @march : VoronoiMesh[] should give you the nearest point (which can be mapped to its curve via an association).  Dropping out the winning curve's points and VoronoiMesh[]ing the surviving points will give the closest point on the second closest curve.  There are only five curves, so precomputing and storing the six meshes should be pretty easy...  (I'm far from a Mathematica currently, or I'd just whack this up myself.)

Comment: @EricTowers. I'm far from an expert on that stuff. I look forward to your solution whenever you have the time!

Comment: @march : First `VoronoiMesh[]`/`Nearest[]` that worked is now an answer.

Comment: @baumannr. Did any of the answers below answer your question? If so, please accept one by whatever criterion you choose!

Answer (score 6):

### Update

I don't know what the "lever rule" is, even after visiting the [Wikipedia page on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever_rule), but here's the routine wrapped up into a `Module`.

```
Clear[interpolateDensity]
interpolateDensity[pnt : {_, _}, fs : {{_InterpolatingFunction, _InterpolatingFunction} ..}, dens_List] /; Length@dens == Length@fs := Module[
  {mins}
  , mins = NMinimize[{#.# &@(pt - Through@#@t), 1. <= t <= #[[1]]["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, t] & /@ fs
  ; Dot @@ Transpose@#/Plus @@ #[[All, 1]] &@ Sort[Transpose[{mins[[All, 1]], dens}]][[1 ;; 2]]
 ]
```

This calculates the density by finding the nearest points on the nearest curves and using the relative distances as weights for the densities of those curves. Usage:

```
Clear[pt, fs, dens]
pt = {3604, 693};
fs = Interpolation /@ Transpose@# & /@ {rho02, rho2, rho50, rho700, rho1000};
dens = {0.2, 2, 50, 700, 1000};
interpolateDensity[pt, fs, dens]
(* 18.7113 *)
```

Alternatively, here is a routine that returns the list of the nearest points along with the densities corresponding to those curves (which you can then use to get the density via the lever rule?):

```
nearestPoints[pnt : {_, _}, fs : {{_InterpolatingFunction, _InterpolatingFunction} ..}, dens_List] /; Length@dens == Length@fs := Module[
  {mins}
  , mins = NMinimize[{#.# &@(pt - Through@#@t), 1. <= t <= #[[1]]["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, t] & /@ fs
  ; Sort[MapThread[{#2[[1]], Through@#1@t /. #2[[2]], #3} &, {fs, mins, dens}]][[1 ;; 2]][[All, 2 ;; 3]]
  ]
```

Usage:

```
nearestPoints[pt, fs, dens]
(* {{{3658.84, 195.126}, 50}, {{3606.93, 7.63443}, 2}} *)
```

### Original Post

For starters, I will not re-paste in your data, but I will define a list of densities:

```
dens = {0.2, 2, 50, 700, 1000};
```

Here's something that I think will work. We first carefully `Interpolate` the data by interpolating the `x` and `y` lists separately to create a parametric interpolating function, like so:

```
fs = Interpolation /@ Transpose@# & /@ {rho02, rho2, rho50, rho700, rho1000};
```

These functions will be defined on the intervals `1` to `Length@rho`:

```
domains = Flatten /@ Through[Transpose[fs][[1]]@"Domain"]
(* {{1., 16.}, {1., 16.}, {1., 17.}, {1., 19.}, {1., 32.}} *)
```

We can plot the `InterpolatingFunction`s to see that they look nice:

```
p1 = Show[
 ListLogPlot[{rho02, rho2, rho50, rho700, rho1000}]
 , ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{#1, Log@#2} & @@ (Through@#@t)], Evaluate@Flatten@{t, #[[1]]["Domain"]}] & /@ fs
]
```

[image]

We now go through the process of minimizing the Euclidean distance between some point

```
pt = {RandomReal[{0, 5000}], RandomReal[{10, 10^3}]}
(* {3604.77,693.335} *)
```

and the curves using the code:

```
mins = NMinimize[{#.# &@(pt - Through@#@t), 1. <= t <= #[[1]]["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, t] & /@ fs;
```

We are minimizing the *square* of the Euclidean distance here, but putting the square root around `#.#` doesn't seem to spit out any errors, so it should work just as well. Obviously, if you think some other distance function is more relevant, then here's where to modify the code. For illustration purposes, we extract the points on the curves as

```
pts = MapThread[Through@#1@t /. Last@#2 &, {fs, mins}]
(* {{3605.06,0.763082},{3607.7,7.63772},{3659.63,195.214},{1921.07,1376.9},{649.59,1537.91}} *)
```

and plot everything together:

```
Show[
  p1
  , ListLogPlot[{pt}, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.02]}]
  , ListLogPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Finally, we choose the closest two points, keeping their distances and their densities:

```
weights = Sort[Transpose[{mins[[All, 1]], dens}]][[1 ;; 2]]
(* {{251135., 50}, {470189., 2}} *)
```

And finally, we linearly interpolate the densities by weighting the densities by the relative distances:

```
density = Dot @@ Transpose@#/Plus @@ #[[All, 1]] &@weights
(* 18.7116 *)
```

All of this can be automated into a neat little `Module`, and of course the code as written isn't the nicest to look at, but I think this works! Take it and run with it.

Answer (score 4):

```
fs = Interpolation /@ {Mean /@ GatherBy[rho1000, First], rho700, rho50, rho2, rho02};



Show[
 ListLogPlot[{Mean /@ GatherBy[rho1000, First], rho700, rho50, rho2, 
   rho02}
  , PlotRange -> All
  , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
  ]
 , Sequence @@ Table[
   With[{f = Evaluate[fs[[k]]]},
    LogPlot[f[t], Evaluate[{t, Sequence @@ First[f["Domain"]]}]]
    ], {k, Length[fs]}]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
minpf[pnt_, func_] := Block[{r, x, xr, y},
  {r, xr} = NMinimize[
    {
     Norm[{pnt, {t, func[t]}}]
     , Between[t, func["Domain"]]
     }, t];
  x = Part[xr, 1, 2];
  {r, x, func[x]}
  ]

minpf[pnt_, func_] := Block[{r, x, xr, y},
  {r, xr} = NMinimize[
    {
     Norm[{pnt, {t, func[t]}}]
     , Between[t, func["Domain"]]
     }, t];
  x = Part[xr, 1, 2];
  {r, x, func[x]}
  ]

findpnt[pnt_] := Rest@First@MinimalBy[Map[minpf[pnt, #] &, fs], First]

findpnt[{100, 1}]
(* {16.964, 0.7855} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Following my OP comment, the first thing that worked.  (Optimized?  Heck, it barely works.  I considered using the rho-sets as their labels, but that just seemed like nuking flies, so string labels.)

```
Module[{rhos, logRhos, minX, maxX, minY, maxY},
  rhos = {rho1000, rho700, rho50, rho2, rho02};
  logRhos = {#[[1]], Log[10, #[[2]]]} & /@ # & /@ rhos;
  {minX, maxX} = MinMax[(Join @@ logRhos)[[All, 1]]];
  {minY, maxY} = MinMax[(Join @@ logRhos)[[All, 2]]];
  {lrs1000, lrs700, lrs50, lrs2, lrs02} = (# - {minX, minY})/({maxX, maxY} - {minX, minY}) & /@ # & /@ logRhos;
  lrsPointToCurve = Association[Sequence[
    (# -> "lrs1000" &) /@ lrs1000,
    (# -> "lrs700" &) /@ lrs700,
    (# -> "lrs50" &) /@ lrs50,
    (# -> "lrs2" &) /@ lrs2,
    (# -> "lrs02" &) /@ lrs02]];
  logRhosScaled = Join[{lrs1000, lrs700, lrs50, lrs2, lrs02}];
  pointToFirstLRSPoint = Nearest[Join @@ logRhosScaled];
  knockout["lrs1000"] = Join[{lrs700, lrs50, lrs2, lrs02}];
  knockout["lrs700"] = Join[{lrs1000, lrs50, lrs2, lrs02}];
  knockout["lrs50"] = Join[{lrs1000, lrs700, lrs2, lrs02}];
  knockout["lrs2"] = Join[{lrs1000, lrs700, lrs50, lrs02}];
  knockout["lrs02"] = Join[{lrs1000, lrs700, lrs50, lrs2}];
  pointToSecondLRSPoint[pt_] := Block[{},
    Nearest[Join @@ knockout[
      lrsPointToCurve[pointToFirstLRSPoint[pt][[1]]]]][pt]];
]

ListPlot[logRhosScaled]
(* Point plot.  Happily, where they're expected to be. *)

VoronoiMesh[Join @@ logRhosScaled]
(* Pretty blue cellulation. *)

pointToFirstLRSPoint[{0.5, 0.5}]
lrsPointToCurve[pointToFirstLRSPoint[{0.5, 0.5}][[1]]]
pointToSecondLRSPoint[{0.5, 0.5}]
lrsPointToCurve[pointToSecondLRSPoint[{0.5, 0.5}][[1]]]
(* {{0.48706, 0.594656}} *)
(* lrs50 *)
(* {{0.559026, 0.359004}} *)
(* lrs2 *)
```

This strictly meets the request : go from an arbitrary point to the two nearest curves. 
The same sort of idea (use an `Association[]`) will let us go from logRhoScaled points to original points if that was actually intended.

Comment: I like it. If for no other reason than for the fact that it's a very different take on the problem.